# Elastic Search : Match Query not working in Nested Bool Filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am able to get data for the following elastic search query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": [],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "gender": "malE"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "sentiment": "positive"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, If I query using "match" - I get error message with 400 status response

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": [],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "gender": "malE"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "sentiment": "positive"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is match query not supported in nested bool filters ?

Since the term query looks for the exact term in the field’s inverted index and I want to query gender data as case_insensitive field - Which approach shall I try ?

Settings of the index :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_keyword": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping for field Gender:

```
{"type":"string","analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"}
```

Comment: if you spend too much time, indexing a lowercased property may be easier

Comment: @johnSmith I did not get you. Do you mean I should search make the attribute to lowercase before searching via term query?

Comment: i mean you most likely index objects and have a mapping for elasticsearch, you can simply add a property and a getter function to your object class that returns the lowercased name, add this field to the elastic mapping and you have no trouble

Comment: i think it makes sense to sanitize the fields that will be indexed so the overall performance of the searchenginge should be touched at last

Comment: Thanks.I am sanitizing the field and making the term lowercase before searching ( eg : {"term" : {"gender":["male"]} ). Was looking for another approach

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error 400 is because there is no `match` filter, only [`match` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), even though there are both [`term` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and [`term` filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html).

Your query can be as simple as this, i.e. no need for a `filtered` query, simply put your `term` and `match` queries into a `bool/should`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": "male"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sentiment": "positive"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .I though match will work in filter dsl as i was using for yes/no output. Other than above, which approach shall I use for case insensitive search - eg  aggs of "very positive" in "sentiment" field.

sentiment filed contains 
["positive","very positive","negative","very negative"]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for ElasticSearch 7.x. As I understand from the question, you would like to use a match query for the `gender` field and a term query for the `sentiment` field. The mappings for each of these field should look like below:

```
"sentiment": { 
       "type": "keyword" 
},
"gender": {
      "type": "text" 
}
```

The corresponding search API would be:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "sentiment": [
                            "very positive", "positive"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "gender": "malE"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This search API returns all the documents where gender is "Male"/"MALE"/"mALe" etc. So, you may have indexed the gender field holding "mALe", but, the match query for  `"gender": "malE"` will still be able to retrieve it. In the latest version of ElasticSearch, if the query is a `match` type, the value (which is  `"gender": "malE"`) will be automatically lower cased internally before search begins. But, it should not be that tough for a client of the API to pass a lowercase to the match query at the onset itself. Coming to the `sentiment` field, since, its a `keyword` field, you can search for values that contain spaces too like `very positive`.